# Condition in Conditional (Ternary) Operator

Tags: c#, if-statement, conditional-statements, ternary-operator

How can I implement this using ternary operator?

```
if(UnitType == null)
{
    a = ElevationType
}
else
{
    a = UnitType
}
```

**Ternary operator**

```
a = UnitType == null ? ElevationType : UnitType;
```

Now I want something like this

```
if(UnitType == null)
{
   if(ElevationType == null)
   {
    a = StructureType
   }
   else{
    a = ElevationType
   }
}
else
{
    a = UnitType
}
```

Can I achieve this using ternary operator? If not, what should be done?

Comment: You can achieve it, but it's going to be a bit hard to read.  Is there a reason why the if-else structure is unacceptable?

Comment: stick with if else structure. Readability is important.

Comment: Don't force use of the ternary. That rarely works out well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
a = (UnitType == null) ? (ElevationType ?? StructureType) : UnitType;
```

But I stand by my comment: this is harder to understand than the if-else would be.

Or, possibly,

```
a = UnitType ?? ElevationType ?? StructureType;
```

That's reasonably clear if you're familiar with the `??` operator.

Comment: Could you pls tell how will we evaluate `??` operator statement?

Comment: @zariakhan [Here you go](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) - or if you don't want to read it, in this case, a is equal to `UnitType` unless it is null, in which case it takes the value of `ElevationType` unless that's null too, in which case it finally takes the value of `StructureType`

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre Cool. Wasn't familiar with this operator. Thanks for such an easy explanation!

Comment: Thanks, @AlfieGoodacre.  Another way to put it is:  `C = A ?? B` is a shortcut for `C = (A != null) ? A : B`, or `if(A!=null) C = A; else C = B;`

Comment: @AnnL. This `a = UnitType ?? ElevationType ?? StructureType;` is super cool! :D

Answer (score 3):

If you need to do this with ternary operators, you can format it for better clarity like this

```
a = UnitType == null ?
    (ElevationType == null ?
        StructureType
        : ElevationType)
    : UnitType;
```

You could also null coalesce, which is the `??` operator, this says if the object is not null, return it, if it is return this instead.

```
a = UnitType == null ?
    (ElevationType ?? StructureType)
    : UnitType;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just write separate method and don't use nested `?` operators, because it is pain for everybody(unreadable, prompt to errors). What if tomorrow your type extend with 2 more Types, your Ternary operator will become hell.

```
public TypeOfA GetTypeOfAMethod()
{
    if(UnitType != null)
       return UnitType;

    if(ElevationType != null)
       return ElevationType;

    if(StructureType != null)
       return StructureType

    return null;

}
```